# Enable pinch to zoom in ScrollViewer insider a ListView in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an app that contains a `ListView` which is made up of several of `ScrollViewer` items. These items are zoomable (I enabled each item by setting `ZoomMode="Enabled"`). When I try to display a single item everything works. However, I would like the zoom to also be enabled when the item is inside a `ListView`. Currently, the scrolling works but it seems that the `ListView` is preventing my ScrollViewer items the pinch gestures (I suppose they are being stolen by ListView).
Here is the code:

```
        <ListView x:Name="pageListView" IsTapEnabled="False">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:CanvasPage x:Name="ink" Width="1000" Height="500"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The `control:CanvasPage` is essentially a `ScrollViewer` that contains an `InkCanvas`.

Comment: did you try to hook the `ManipulationDelta` event? It should be invoked when you pinch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationdelta

Comment: You set IsHitTestVisible of ListViewItem as false, the contained area of this UIElement cannot be used for hit testing. So you can't zoom the content of scrollViewer, you need to set the IsHitTestVisible as true.